# Mocking static methods with PowerMock and Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermock

I'm trying to verify a call to `java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection` using JUnit, Mockito, and PowerMock.

Here's my test case:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(DriverManager.class)
public class MySQLDatabaseConnectionFactoryTest {

    private ConfigurationService configurationService;
    private MySQLDatabaseConnectionFactory reference;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        this.reference = new MySQLDatabaseConnectionFactory();
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetConnection() throws SQLException {
//      setup
        Connection connection = mock(Connection.class);

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(DriverManager.class);

        when(DriverManager.getConnection(anyString(), anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(connection);

//      run
        this.reference.getConnection();

//      verify
        PowerMockito.verifyStatic();
        DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://myhost:1111/database", "username", "password");
    }

}
```

Here's the code under test:

```
public class MySQLDatabaseConnectionFactory implements
        DatabaseConnectionFactory {

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection(IApplicationInstance appInstance) {         
        try {
            return DriverManager.getConnection(String.format("jdbc:mysql://%s:%d/%s", 
                    MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_PORT, MYSQL_DATABASE), MYSQL_USERNAME, MYSQL_PASSWORD);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Interestingly enough, this code fails with a `java.sql.SQLException`:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://myhost:1111/database
```

Now, I could easily just make sure that my SQL driver (MySQL in this case) is loaded at test time, but why isn't the static method completely mocked out without side-effects?

## Update:

I've better isolated the problem. I've added a test method to my test case which tries getting a connection from `DriverManager`:

```
@Test
public void testSomething() {
    Connection conn = mock(Connection.class);
    mockStatic(DriverManager.class);
    when(DriverManager.getConnection(anyString())).thenReturn(conn);
    Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("whut");
    verifyStatic();
    DriverManager.getConnection("whut");
}
```

This test actually passes, while the other test still fails. It seems that PowerMock isn't mocking the reference to the class inside of `MySQLDatabaseConnectionFactory`. How can I work around  this?

Comment: You are invoking `this.reference.getConnection();` in test, but this `public Connection getConnection(IApplicationInstance appInstance)`. Can you clarify this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Changing your `@PrepareForTest` annotation value to `MySQLDatabaseConnectionFactory.class` will resolve this issue.

> This annotation tells PowerMock to prepare certain classes for testing. Classes needed to be defined using this annotation are typically those that needs to be byte-code manipulated. This includes final classes, classes with final, private, static.

In this situation PowerMockito have to replace invocation to static method `DriverManager.getConnection` with mocked code. This is done with usage of byte-code manipulation.

### Full code

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(MySQLDatabaseConnectionFactory.class)
public class MySQLDatabaseConnectionFactoryTest {

    private MySQLDatabaseConnectionFactory reference;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        reference = new MySQLDatabaseConnectionFactory();
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetConnection() throws SQLException {

        // given
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(DriverManager.class);
        BDDMockito.given(DriverManager.getConnection(anyString(), anyString(), anyString()))
             .willReturn(mock(Connection.class));

        // when
        reference.getConnection();

        // then
        PowerMockito.verifyStatic();
        DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://myhost:1111/database", "username", "password");
    }
}
```

*Thanks to [@Szpak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/313516/szpak) for helping me to resolve this issue!*